# Java thread join() confusion

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to follow this example in order to understand the join() method:

```
class PrintDemo {

   public void printCount() {

      try {

         for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
      }
   }
}

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   PrintDemo  PD;

   ThreadDemo(String name,  PrintDemo pd) {
      threadName = name;
      PD = pd;
   }

   public void run() {

      synchronized(PD) {
         PD.printCount();
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   public void start () {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );

      if (t == null) {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
}

public class TestThread {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();

      ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo("Thread - 1 ", PD);
      ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo("Thread - 2 ", PD);

      T1.start();
      T2.start();

      // wait for threads to end
      try {
         T1.join();
         T2.join();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Interrupted");
      }
   }
}
```

I understood that T1.join() for example makes the main thread wait for T1 to finish in order to continue with its flow. Am I correct here?

So, I modified the code like this:

```
      System.out.println("1");
      T1.start();
      System.out.println("2");
      T2.start();

      // wait for threads to end
      try {
         System.out.println("3");
         T1.join();
         System.out.println("4");
         T2.join();
         System.out.println("5");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Interrupted");
      }
```

in order to try and follow the complete flow.

And this is what I get every time:

```
1
Starting Thread - 1 
2
Starting Thread - 2 
3
4
5
Counter   ---   5
Counter   ---   4
Counter   ---   3
Counter   ---   2
Counter   ---   1
Thread Thread - 1  exiting.
Counter   ---   5
Counter   ---   4
Counter   ---   3
Counter   ---   2
Counter   ---   1
Thread Thread - 2  exiting.
```

and I cannot explain it...

How come the counter prints were printed after the "5" character???
I probably don't understand well the join issue...

Comment: @Zoe You don't seem to know what `Thread.join()` does, you may want to refrain from posting such comments as they only lead to confusion.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], include all relevant code, not just your modifications.

Comment: I just took a peek at the code in that tutorial, and it is confusingly bad by starting new threads from a thread start. I strongly suggest you stop using that site, it seems to be rubbish.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Mark, I added a link to the complete code. Is it still preferred to paste the whole code?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I must say I also didn't like this style of code...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Could not agree more. If the goal is to teach synchronization, you don't need threads spawning threads to demonstrate that. If the goal is to demonstrate that waiting for a thread to die does not necessitate waiting for it's children to die, the synchronization guff just gets in the way.

Comment: Yes, you should include the code in your question: questions must be self-contained.

Comment: I second @MarkRotteveel: overriding `Thread.run()` is moderately iffy, overriding `Thread.start()` is a massive no-no, and then to start another thread from it is a Very Bad Idea™. I'd use the [official Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), which aren't perfect but aren't this bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Micheal said, your main thread are not joinning to "desire" thread, perhaps this code can help you to clarify. It helps Main thread to join with the inside threads.

```
class PrintDemo {

   public void printCount() {

      try {

         for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
      }
   }
}

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   PrintDemo  PD;

   ThreadDemo(String name,  PrintDemo pd) {
      threadName = name;
      PD = pd;
   }

   public void run() {

      synchronized(PD) {
         PD.printCount();
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   public void start () {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );

      if (t == null) {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }

   public void joinInsideThread() throws InterruptedException {
       if (t != null){
           t.join();
       }
   }
}

public class TestThread {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();

      ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo("Thread - 1 ", PD);
      ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo("Thread - 2 ", PD);

      System.out.println("1");
      T1.start();
      System.out.println("2");
      T2.start();

      // wait for threads to end
      try {
         System.out.println("3");
         T1.joinInsideThread();
         System.out.println("4");
         T2.joinInsideThread();
         System.out.println("5");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Interrupted");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @dushkin I have tried to keep the essence of your example, but keep in mind that it is a poorly designed example for the purpose of teaching thread synchronization.

Comment: @dushkin Please,  read carefully the Michael and Mark Rotteveel comments. I agree with them.

Answer (score 6):

You start a thread (A) which starts another thread (B).

You wait for thread A to finish - which is almost immediate as it barely does anything besides kick off thread B - but thread B is still running independently.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying ... to understand the join() method

`t.join()` is trivially easy to understand.  All it does is wait for thread `t` to die.  It doesn't do anything else.  Most especially, it does not do anything to thread `t`.

A call to `t.join()` will do nothing, and return immediately if `t` has already finished.  Otherwise it will do nothing, and it will not return until `t` *is* finished.